# Invertibility of a Vandermonde-like matrix.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&\ldots&7\\1&2^2&\ldots&7^2\\\cdot&\cdot&&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&&\cdot\\\cdot&\cdot&&\cdot\\1&2^7&\ldots&7^7\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then it is required to show the invertibility of this matrix.
I tried using the Gaussian elimination, but the matrix becomes too complicated to handle; then I used induction, but found no apparent pattern to complete the induction step. Also, I have no idea how to compute the determinant of such a matrix.
Hence every hint or reference is much appreciated.

Comment: I would just factor out $2,3,4,5,6,7$ from the $2$nd through $7$th columns - then the remaining matrix is exactly a Vandermonde matrix (or its transpose).

Comment: @GregMartin Why not post an answer to close the issue? Thanks for your sharp pointer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested: I would just factor out 2,3,4,5,6,7 from the 2nd through 7th columns - then the remaining matrix is exactly a Vandermonde matrix (or its transpose).

Alternatively (less efficiently but perhaps giving deeper understanding) you could replace the entire first column by $x,x^2,\dots,x^7$ and consider the determinant as a polynomial of degree 7 in $x$. You know that it vanishes when $x=2,3,4,5,6,7$ because of identical columns, and (unlike the standard Vandermonde proof) it also vanishes when $x=0$. So it must be a multiple of $x(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6)(x-7)$ and you only need to find the leading constant. That can be done by induction, perhaps, since the coefficient of $x^7$ is just the upper-right $6\times 6$ minor.

Comment: This alternative approach is quite interesting as well! Thanks. :)